# String permutations in lexigraphic order without inversions/reversions

Tags: string, algorithm, perl, permutation, combinatorics

The problem:

I would like to generate a list of permutations of strings in lexigraphical but excluding string inversions. For instance, if I have the following string: abc, I would like to generate the following list

```
abc
acb
bac
```

instead of the typical

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

An alternative example would look something like this:

```
100
010
```

instead of

```
100
010 
001
```

Currently, I can generate the permutations using perl, but I am not sure on how to best remove the reverse duplicates.

I had thought of applying something like the following:

```
create map with the following:
1)   100
2)   010
3)   001
then perform the reversion/inversion on each element in the map and create a new map with:

 1') 001
 2') 010
 3') 100
```

then compare and if the primed list value matches the original value, leave it in place, if it is different, if it's index is greater than the median index, keep it, else remove.

Trouble is, I am not sure if this is an efficient approach or not.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: It is acceptable to generate `abc acb bca` instead of `abc acb bac`? Don't know if it matters.

Comment: Up to how many elements (how long can strings be)?

Comment: @zdim upto 8 elements

Comment: @ikegami What you suggest would be acceptable, so long as it doesn't include bca in the list.

Comment: With "up to 8" even a brute-force check for inverses (additional O(N^2) complexity), after _all_ permutations are formed, would be just fine -- for a single run.  In which case you can unify all cases, no tricks needed.  If you have many many runs then of course it adds up.

Comment: Can you also clarify: are these two the only cases to consider?  So either `abcde` or `10000`, no `abbcd` or `11000`? (See my answer)

Comment: I completed my answer to cover all cases (and thus rearranged it).

Comment: @zim the cases of 11000 or 11100  also of interest (so yes, duplicate elements of both symbols)

Comment: OK, then for that case (`0` and `1`) you use the last section -- let me know if it'd be helpful to add the code to exclude inverses.  The good thing there is that variations are much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities represented by examples are for permutations where all elements are different (`abcd`), or for variations of two symbols where one appears exactly once (`1000`). More general cases are addressed as well.

**Non-repeating elements (permutations)**

Here we can make use of [Algorithm::Permute](http://search.cpan.org/~edpratomo/Algorithm-Permute-0.12/Permute.pm), and of the particular observation: 
*Each permutation where the first element is greater than its last need be excluded*. It comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081579/generating-permutations-which-are-not-mirrors-of-each-other), brought up in the [answer by ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928157/4653379).

This rule holds as follows. Consider substrings of a string without its first and last elements. For each such substring, all permutations of the string must contain its inverse. One of these, padded with last and first, is thus the inverse of the string. By construction, for each substring there is exactly one inverse. Thus permutations with swapped first and last elements of each string need be excluded.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Algorithm::Permute;

my $size = shift || 4;
my @arr = ('a'..'z')[0..$size-1];  # 1..$size for numbers

my @res;    
Algorithm::Permute::permute { 
    push @res, (join '', @arr) unless $arr[0] gt $arr[-1] 
} @arr; 

say for @arr;
```

Problems **with repetead elements** (`abbcd`) can be treated the exact same way as above, and we need to also prune duplicates as permutations of `b` generate `abbcd` and `abbcd` (same)

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';
# build @res the same way as above ...
my @res = uniq @res;
```

Doing this during construction would not reduce complexity nor speed things up.

The `permute` is quoted as the fastest method in the module, by far. It is about an order of magnitude faster than the other modules I tested (below), taking about 1 second for 10 elements on my system. But note that this problem's complexity is *factorial* in size. It blows up really fast.

**Two symbols, where one appears exactly once (variations)**

This is different and the above module is not meant for it, nor would the exclusion criterion work.  There are other modules, see at the end. However, the problem here is very simple.

Start from `(1,0,0,...)` and 'walk' `1` along the list, up to the "midpoint" – which is the half for even sized list (4 for 8-long), or next past half for odd sizes (5 for 9-long). All strings obtained this way, by moving `1` by one position up to midpoint, form the set. The second "half" are their inversions.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $size = shift || 4;
my @n = (1, map { 0 } 1..$size-1);   

my @res = (join '', @n);       # first element of the result

my $end_idx = ( @n % 2 == 0 ) ? @n/2 - 1 : int(@n/2);

foreach my $i (0..$end_idx-1)  # stop one short as we write one past $i
{
    @n[$i, $i+1] = (0, 1);     # move 1 by one position from where it is
    push @res, join '', @n;
}

print "$_\n" for @res;
```

We need to stop before the last index since it has been filled in the previous iteration.

This can be modified if **both symbols (`0,1`) may appear repeatedly**, but it is far simpler to use a module and then exclude inverses. The [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) has routines for all needs here.  For all variations of `0` and `1` of lenght `$size`, where both may repeat

```
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(variations_with_repetition);

my @rep_vars = variations_with_repetition([0, 1], $size);
```

Inverse elements can then be excluded by a brute-force search, with *O(N<sup>2</sup>)* complexity at worst.

Also note [Math::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~allenday/Math-Combinatorics-0.09/lib/Math/Combinatorics.pm).

Comment: I don't know why it was down voted, because it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Hobbes Thank you for the comment.  I just don't like unsubstantiated downvotes (except when glaring and obvious to experts, or in few other circumstances). I think that they don't do any good favors to anyone, only puzzle and deter.  Most of the time that actually _harms_ future readers. I'll do all I can to fix any and every thing that I know is off since I firstly want to leave good content behind. But for this a comment is immensely helpful, or often necessary.  However, all posts on this page got downvoted so I guess it's about something else.

Comment: @Hobbes  I removed my original comment asking about that -- don't mean to leave your response hanging, but I never saw such comments achieve anything (it was typed in a spur of the moment).  Thank you for responding to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the suggested duplicate [Generating permutations which are not mirrors of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081579/generating-permutations-which-are-not-mirrors-of-each-other) doesn't deal with repeated elements (because that wasn't part of that question) so naively following it would include e.g. both 0100 and  0010.  So this isn't an exact duplicate.  But the idea applies.

Generate all the permutations but filter only for those with `$_ le reverse $_`.  I think this is essentially what you suggest in the question, but there's no need to compute a map when a simple expression applied to each permutation will tell you whether to include it or not.